# Passing a Dictionary through Encrypted Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, deserialization

I have a dictionary object which i would like to encrypt, then put it in a querystring, then decrypt it on the other side.

I'm using JavaScriptSerializer for this. Now i've tried this on the same page onload, and it worked. So the encrypt/decrypt extension methods im using are working. This leads me to believe there's some issue going on with the querystring.

e.g.

```
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        d.Add("ID", "123456");
        d.Add("Name", "HELLO TEST");
        d.Add("Email", "test@email.com");
        var s = js.Serialize(d).EncryptString();
        var ds = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(s.DecryptString());
        @ViewBag.Test = ds["Name"];
```

In the above example, `EncryptString()` and `DecryptString()` are the extension methods i'm using. This works as intended, so it pulls the correct value for `"Name"`.

I run into problems when I put the serialized encrypted string into the querystring then try and decode it.

**So on the first page**, i have something like this:

```
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        d.Add("ID", "123456");
        d.Add("Name", "HELLO TEST");
        d.Add("Email", "test@email.com");
        var s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(js.Serialize(d).EncryptString());
```

`s` is then used as the querystring.

**On the receiving page**, i have this:

```
public ActionResult Display(string r)
{
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var decryptedString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(r).DecryptString();
        var s = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(decryptedString);
        return View();
}
```

This throws an error: `System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.` This errors on the decryptstring line.

I don't get what's going on... I'm urlencoding the text before it goes into the querystring, then urldecoding it before it's deserialized..

**EDIT**

Figured it out.. I was encrypting it twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that you don't need to UrlDecode your string, because MVC will have done that before assigning the value of your `r` parameter. Try decrypting `r` directly.

And of course, I have to issue the warning: what you're doing here seems like a very bad idea. Whatever you're trying to accomplish by sending this encrypted dictionary in the URL, there is almost certainly a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: @rudeovskizebear: Can you show us how the URL is being generated from this `s` value?

Comment: Well i tried dictionary as i wasn't sure what else to use. But after i got it to work, i got an error saying Dictionary serialization is unsupported. i've now converted it to a list instead. What do you recommend?

Comment: @rudeovskizebear: I can't really give a recommendation unless I can understand what you're trying to accomplish here. It looks like you're relying on this URL parameter to maintain information from one request to another. It looks like you don't actually want the user to be able to see or play with this data, so you're encrypting it. Why not keep the information in the session or recreate it from the database on the next request?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some characters don't roundtrip the way you expect (i.e. "+" tends to become space in this case).

Check with Fiddler (or any other HTTP debugging tool) what is actually send to/from your server. Than check if string that comes to you "Display" action - cood chance that you see what is wrong.